# css3 gradient center fade

Tags: css

does anyone know how to make a center gradient fade from light to dark with about an offset of about -20px top?

this is what i've been able to do so far

```
background-color:#303030;
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#282828,#616161,#303030);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#282828,#616161,#303030);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,#282828,#616161,#303030);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left,#282828,#616161,#303030);
background-image:linear-gradient(left,#282828,#616161,#303030);
```

[image]

Comment: What's going on in your image? The bit on the right certainly *looks* like it's working correctly... what's wrong with it?

Comment: @DragoonWraith the right side is as close as i could get to the center gradient... I guess I'm being picky about the lighter line going down the middle. its not spreading like the PS design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left isn't a linear gradient, it looks radial. Here's an example of how to do one with an offset:
http://codepen.io/mastastealth/pen/ocIaz

Basically use something like this (apply proper prefixes, and not supported in older IEs):

```
background: radial-gradient(center 20px, circle, #616161 0%, #616161 20%, #282828 100%);
```

Comment: +1 good catch. It does appear to be more of a radial gradient than a linear one. Though you should probably include your code here in your answer in case of future link rot.

Comment: thanks, did you use a generator if so do you have a link for it... if not what does each number after the color code represent the about of fade that it will do?

Comment: You can use www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor to help visualize your gradients (add offset manually). The % represents the "position" of the color. In radial, 0% would be the center, 100% the most outer edge, & you can just play with the middle one(s) depending how you want your gradient!

Comment: I don't think a radial gradient is at all what the OP was asking for. If you look in the LHS image, the lines of uniform colour are vertical. It's a linear gradient. The problem is that the OP wants colour stops at (approximately) 100px from the left and 100px from the right, and with a variable-width container.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "offset of about 20 px at the top" means that you want the gradient shifted down 20px? If that's the case, you need to create some element like a div, apply your gradient, and then position it down about 20 pixels.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNADe/1/). This can be accomplished many different ways; here I just used absolute positioning:

```
<div id="abc"></div>

#abc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* gradient here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you can't do this with a single gradient, but you can do it with two gradients in two nested elements. While a gradient fills a whole image, you can specify a transparent colour stop.

Your outer element takes care of the left hand side, with a 'to right' linear gradient, which fades to the centre colour. The inner element takes care of the right hand side, with a 'to left' gradient which fades to transparency, and thus lets the left hand side gradient appear.

```
<div class="gradient">
    <div class="gradient-inner">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    red,
    green 40px
  );
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.gradient-inner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    red,
    green 40px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40px
  );
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i knw this is old, but seriously? ever since we've had the ability to do gradients, we have been able to put MORE THAN 2 color stops....